# Desktop launcher for terminal apps

Tags: command-line, launcher, icons

I have software to run opensim, it requires the terminal window to start, run and shut down.

I have 3 instances of it running in 3 terminal windows, with mysql for the 3 databases.
Normally to start each instance I have to open 3 terminal windows, then in each I have to type out the path to the OpenSim.exe file. The commands are like this below but the directory name on the desktop differs for each as there are 3 seperate instances, example for one;

```
cd Desktop/mexico/bin

mono OpenSim.exe
```

This is a little pain to type out each time, so I wanted to place 3 icons on the desktop I could just click start each, I thought I had it right with this below but there was an error when the terminal started, and now I remember I forgot to include the mono command but I'm not sure how the syntax should go. This is what I tried, and I saved the file as opensim.desktop and saved it ON the desktop;

```
[Desktop Entry]
    Name=OpenSim
    Comment=Opensim launcher
    Exec= /Desktop/mexico/bin/OpenSim.exe
    Icon=/Desktop/mexico/icon.png
    Terminal=true
    Type=Application
    Categories=Games;
    StartupNotify=true
```

Where did I go wrong in there and how should I adjust that to make this work?
I figure I'll have to make 3 of these and just name them opensim1 2 and 3 and have the 3 icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).

You'll want to specify `Path=~/Desktop/mexico/bin` and change the `Exec` line to `Exec=mono OpenSim.exe`.  There is no need to have multiple shortcuts, one should work.  If you want these to act as normal application launchers, you should put them wherever the rest of your `.desktop` files are located.

Comment: That was great, I added the Path line and made a few changes and it worked fine.